# Keras Custom Median Pooling Layer

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

Is there a way to create a custom layer that computes the median of each pool, rather than the mean or max? I am using tensorflow as the backend

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522517/custom-median-pooling-in-tensorflow

Comment: I did, thank you. Just took me a little while to get it working with my model. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom median pooling in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522517/custom-median-pooling-in-tensorflow)