# Building a minpool layer in tensorflow 1.15

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I was asked in an assigment to code a **min**pool layer in tensorflow 1 (1.15, to be specific). I looked at a lot of resources online, but honestly I am somewhat lost. I mean, I have seen an implementation of **mean**pool layer here:

[Custom median pooling in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522517/custom-median-pooling-in-tensorflow)

but I really don't understand what going on there. I read the docs for `tf.extract_image_patches` and couldn't realy understand what going on there, and the rest of the answers are not clear as well.

I know how to implement this layer with numpy, so if there is an easy way to take a tf tensor, pass it through a numpy function and return in back as a tensor - and integrate this function as a layer inside my CNN - this will be great.

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this (pseudocode):

```
neg_input = -1*input
max_of_neg = max_pool(neg_input)
min_pooled = -1*max_pool
```

The idea here is that the maximum of -x is the (negative of the) minimum of x. So we take the negative, do max pooling on that, and then take the negative again.
No custom pooling ops necessary -- actually creating a custom pooling that is as performant as the built-in ones is probably quite difficult unless you're comfortable with C++/CUDA coding.

Comment: thank you - this is a smart idea, but the idea here is to learn how to create custome layers by ourselfs :)